# Permutations and Combinations - Disc101

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

**In how many ways can 32 people walk through 7 doors?**

My attempt :-

**C(32,7)**

But on the test I got this answer incorrect so can anybody help me figure out the actual answer?

Comment: is the order they are walking into the doors important or not?

Comment: What constitutes a different way for the 32 people to "walk through the doors?"  Is the only thing that matters which door each person walked through but not necessarily the order?  Does it matter the order of each door individually?  Does it matter the order of the doors combined?  (E.g. Fred goes through door one and then John goes through door two.  Is this different than John going through door two and then Fred going through door one?)

Comment: I assumed it to be no. But it did not specify that the order does matter.

Comment: @JMoravitz The question was not so detailed so I assumed order does not matter.

Comment: Then the answer below is fine.  Ask the question of "which door did person $i$ walk through?" over and over.  $C(32,7)$ counts the number of ways of picking seven people from the thirty two to do something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the answer should be $C(32,7)$. I'd argue as follows: For each of the $32$ people, you have $7$ possible choices of doors. This means that you have to choose between $7$ doors $32$ times, so the answer would be $7^{32}$.

EDIT: My first answer above rests on the assumption that all of the $32$ people are distinct.

If on the other hand, the people are indistinguishable, then the answer is

$$C(32+7-1,7-1) = C(38,6).$$

This is a [famous combinatorial problem known as stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

Comment: My professor had posted a similar question with different values and his answer was :- C(19,4) , which i cannot understand how. 
Question was 15 people through 5 doors.

Comment: @Luke find the exact wording of that problem.  An answer like that would imply that the doors are considered distinct, but the people themselves are considered indistinct and order is unimportant.  HowDoIMath's answer here assumes order is not important, doors are distinct and people are distinct as well.

Comment: @JMoravitz , Here is the exact question :- In how many ways can 15 people walk through 5 doors? (No details were given so it should be assumed that order is not important) and the answer to this was C(19,4).

Comment: If you can't tell the people apart, then $C(19,4)$ would be the right answer (i.e. if you have two people and three doors, and it is the same thing, if person 1 walks through door 2 and person 2 walks through door 3 as if person 1 walks through door 3 and person 2 walks through door 2): If the people are indistinguishable, but the doors are distinguishable, then $C(19,4)$ would be right. @Luke

Comment: okay, so I don't have a sensible answer but I found a theorem in book and here is how the answer came : C(15+5-1, 5-1). It is some sort of formula given the two values 15 and 5.

Comment: So the answer for my main question would be C(32+7-1, 7-1) = C(38,6).

Comment: @Luke yeah, that would be right, if you can't tell any two persons apart. Of course if would have been nicer, if the problem had included that assumption for clarity.

Comment: @Luke During an exam, you should always be allowed to ask for clarification on problems like these.  Depending on what is or isn't considered distinct and whether order does or does not matter will completely change the answer.  Be familiar with how to solve as many of the possible interpretations as you can.  If you are in a situation where you are not able to ask for clarification, then specify which of the interpretations your answer is for.  Even if it is not the intended interpretation, you might still receive full or most of the credit for correct work for a different interpretation.

Comment: @HowDoIMath , I have a terrible professor! That's all I can say. 
Appreciate the help :)

Comment: @JMoravitz I will surely work on it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Many times you have to use your commonsense to interpret a question.

Had the question been about *rats*, say,
I would take them as indistinguishable (unless otherwise specified)

And for *people* I would take them as distinguishable (unless otherwise specified)

My ans is $7^{32}$, each person having $7$ choices for doors.